# Storing tags into ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, string, elasticsearch, nest

I have an ElasticSearch database in which I store simple user generated strings (aka messages). Each string can have a number of tags attached to it. The total no. of tags is known a priori but *could* increase over time (I don't want to lock me out in case I feel the need to create a new message tags, i.e. I don't want to re-index my entire database to add a new tag).

Now, the system should be able to perform freetext search over the messages (that's comes almost for free with ElasticSearch) and to search for messages with a specific tag (or a subset of tags).

What's the best way to define the ES document? For the time being I do care mostly about the easiest way to implement the NEST query for it.

Please note that the search should be performed at the ES level, not the application level! I don't want to retrieve all the messages and then filter them out manually on my business logic.

Possible options I can think of:

- List of tag Ids
- List of tag names (the actual tag name)
- Bitfield (i-th tag present = i-th bit set, i-th tag not present = i-th bit clear)   (does ES support bitwise operation natively?)

My current document:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "Message")]
public class MessageRecord
{
    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.No)]
    public List<int> CatList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elasticsearch can index arrays as well. So if you have a document like following:

```
{ 
  stringContent: "Some string content",
  tags: ["important", "revisit", "elasticsearch"]
}
```

you will be able to search on this using tags. Elasticsearch will map each element of array with the document.

When it comes to updating, please note Elasticsearch is NRT(Near realtime). You can update the document, and elasticsearch will subsequently update the document and reindex the document (Not the entire index).

Comment: The "right" answer, note that most likely tags should be `not_analyzed`.

Comment: Unless you want to support autocomplete or fuzziness on your search for tags

Comment: True, in that case you could index analyzed and not_analyzed versions of tags. not_analyzed is handy for at least terms aggregation.